# Send emails as company's group Google Apps address, from my personal Gmail

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

My company has a `engineers@corp.com` "group" email address (Google Apps Free edition) to which I belong. I receive emails sent to this address, and when logged into Gmail as `nico@corp.com` I successfully configured "Send mail as" so that I can now send emails as `engineers@corp.com`.

Now, I want to **send emails as** `engineers@corp.com` **when logged into my personal Gmail** `nico@gmail.com`. Here is what I tried:

- Click *Settings* > *Add another email address you own*
- In the popup, fill "*Name*" as "Corp Engineers", "*Email address*" as "engineers@corp.com", and leave "*Treat as an alias*" checked
- Click "*Next step*"
- For some reason, a form called *Send mail through your SMTP server* appears. It did not appear when logged as `nico@corp.com`… anyway I fill it. The *SMTP* field is pre-filled with `smtp.mycorp.com`, which does not exist (DNS error) so I use `smtp.gmail.com` instead. After pressing *Add account* this error appears:

[image: Add another email address you own: Authentication failed. Please check your username/password.]

I also tried filling with my `nico@gmail.com` account's details, different error:

[image: Add another email address you own: Authentication failed. Please check your username/password. Server response: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted.]

How to do?

*Note: I can send as `nico@corp.com` from my personal Gmail, I have configured that already. The question here is for the group email `engineers@corp.com`.*

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it seems that Google has changed its policy for Google Apps Email service. I also noticed this new behaviours a few weeks ago. Before, I was to use a "Send as Gmail" (I don't remember the exact wording) functionality.